# Multiprocessed reduce function hangs when task queue size of above 1200 elements in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, reduce

the program works fine untill the size of the `to_sum` list reaches about 1150. Afterwards, the processes will hang at the first point where `task_queue = result_queue`. They will successfully fill the result queue and terminate, but then will hang. This problem does not happen if the size of the array is below 1150.
Restarting the computer sometimes allows for the program to work with an array of bigger size before it hangs due to size, but it is always around the 1100-1300 range.
Do you have any idea what could cause this problem?

```
    import multiprocessing

class CustomProcess(multiprocessing.Process):

    def __init__(self, name, task_queue, result_queue, lock, chunks=2, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(name=name, *args, **kwargs)
        self.name = name
        self.task_queue = task_queue
        self.result_queue = result_queue
        self.chunks = chunks
        self.lock = lock

    def run(self):
        while True:
            """
            Using a lock to avoid a race condition where 2 threads both get a number, then
            both to get another, but it is None so they both put the number back resulting in a result queue
            with bigger size. For example:
            Expected result_queue_size = 500, current_queue_size 499, after summation of 1 and 2 we will add 3 to result queue
            achieving 500.
            With race condition result is 501.
            [1, 2, None, None]
            Thread 1 gets 1.
            Thread 2 gets 2.
            Thread 1 gets None and puts 1 in result queue instead of getting 2 and summing.
            Thread 2 gets None and puts 2 in result queue instead of just getting the first None and returning.
            A lock on both gets removes the race condition.
            """
            with self.lock:
                if not self.task_queue.empty():
                    number_1 = self.task_queue.get()
                    self.task_queue.task_done()
                    if number_1 is None:
                        #Poison pill - terminate.
                        print(f"Terminated {self.name}")
                        return
                else:
                    #Queue empty - terminate.
                    return
                if not self.task_queue.empty():
                    number_2 = self.task_queue.get()
                    self.task_queue.task_done()
                    if number_2 is None:
                        #Cannot compute sum of 1 number so just add number_1 to result_queue and terminate since poison pill
                        #acquired.
                        self.result_queue.put(number_1)
                        print(f"Terminated {self.name}")
                        return
                else:
                    self.result_queue.put(number_1)
                    #Queue empty, put the 1 number in result queue and terminate.
                    return
            self.result_queue.put(number_1 + number_2)


def multiprocess_sum(array):
    if len(array) == 1:
        return array[0]
    lock = multiprocessing.Lock()
    task_queue = multiprocessing.JoinableQueue()
    [task_queue.put(element) for element in to_sum]
    task_queue_size = len(array)

    while task_queue_size > 1:
        print(task_queue.qsize(), task_queue_size)
        result_queue = multiprocessing.JoinableQueue()
        processes = [CustomProcess(name=str(i), task_queue=task_queue, result_queue=result_queue, lock=lock)
                    for i in range(8)]
        [task_queue.put(None) for process in processes]
        [process.start() for process in processes]
        #[process.join() for process in processes]
        task_queue.join()
        task_queue = result_queue
        task_queue_size = task_queue_size // 2 + task_queue_size % 2
    return result_queue.get()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    to_sum = [i for i in range(1350)]
    """
    If range is below 1200, the program will run and compute everything correctly.
    If it is above it, it will hang at the first halving, the moment the first task_queue is empty and the
    result_queue becomes the new task_queue. 
    Computer restart will make the range values fluctuate, yesterday it would hang at 1177 but run fine up to 1776.
    Queue pipe full???
    """
    print(sum(to_sum))
    for i in range(5):
        print(multiprocess_sum(to_sum))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is too long for a comment, and so:

First and foremost, calls to `empty` and `qsize` on multiprocessing queues are *unreliable* and should not be used (read the docs). Second, the lock you are using prevents any real multiprocessing from occurring since the bulk of processing done in your `run` method is being executed serially. Third, to add up 1359 numbers requires 1349 additions (how can it be otherwise?). So simply divide your 1350 numbers into 8 lists as evenly as possible and have each of your processes sum their lists and return the results. Then just add the 8 returned values to get the final result.

As the size of your `to_sum` grows the more negligible is the contribution to the total running time made by the final addition of the 8 partial sums.

```py
import multiprocessing
from functools import reduce
from operator import add

class CustomProcess(multiprocessing.Process):

    def __init__(self, name, task_queue, result_queue, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(name=name, *args, **kwargs)
        self.task_queue = task_queue
        self.result_queue = result_queue

    def run(self):
        self.result_queue.put(reduce(add, self.task_queue.get(), 0))

def split(iterable, n):  # function to split iterable in n even parts
    if type(iterable) is range and iterable.step != 1:
        # algorithm doesn't work with steps other than 1:
        iterable = list(iterable)
    l = len(iterable)
    n = min(l, n)
    k, m = divmod(l, n)
    return (iterable[i * k + min(i, m):(i + 1) * k + min(i + 1, m)] for i in range(n))

N_PROCESSES = 8

def multiprocess_sum(l):
    if len(l) == 1:
        return l[0]

    task_queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
    lists = split(l, N_PROCESSES)
    for l in lists:
        task_queue.put(l)

    result_queue = multiprocessing.Queue()

    processes = [
        CustomProcess(name=str(i), task_queue=task_queue, result_queue=result_queue)
        for i in range(N_PROCESSES)
    ]
    for process in processes:
        process.start()

    the_sum = reduce(add, (result_queue.get() for _ in range(N_PROCESSES)), 0)

    for process in processes:
        process.join()

    return the_sum

if __name__ == "__main__":
    to_sum = list(range(1350))
    print(sum(to_sum))
    for i in range(5):
        print(multiprocess_sum(to_sum))
```

Prints:

```None
910575
910575
910575
910575
910575
910575
```

**I wonder how large the `to_sum` list must be to gain any time savings by using multiprocessing for this particular problem.**

**Update**

To do the reduction per the OP's attempt, I would use the following code. Since calls to `qsize` on a queue are not reliable, we keep track of the number of items on a queue using a sharable integer `Value` that must be incremented or decremented under control of a lock. We also create the processes once. Read the comments, please.

```py
import multiprocessing

class CustomProcess(multiprocessing.Process):

    def __init__(self,
                 name,
                 task_queue,
                 result_queue,
                 task_queue_size,
                 result_queue_size,
                 condition,
                 *args,
                 **kwargs
                 ):
        super().__init__(name=name, *args, **kwargs)
        self.name = name
        self.task_queue = task_queue
        self.result_queue = result_queue
        self.task_queue_size = task_queue_size
        self.result_queue_size = result_queue_size
        self.condition = condition

    def run(self):
        task_queue = self.task_queue
        result_queue = self.result_queue
        task_queue_size = self.task_queue_size
        result_queue_size = self.result_queue_size
        condition = self.condition

        task_queue_size_lock = task_queue_size.get_lock()

        while True:
            # When the task queue size goes down to zero, the main process
            # will move all the items from the result queue to the
            # task queue and then set the new task queue size.
            # We must not attempt to process the task queue while
            # this occurs, i.e. we must wait until the task queue size
            # is again non-zero:
            with condition:
                while task_queue_size.value == 0:
                    condition.wait()

            # No need to acquire lock for this test:
            if task_queue_size.value < 0:
                return # We are done

            # There is no gurantee we will find anything on the input queue:
            task_queue_size_lock.acquire()
            if task_queue_size.value == 0:
                task_queue_size_lock.release()
                continue

            number_1 = task_queue.get()
            task_queue_size.value -= 1
            if task_queue_size.value == 0:
                # put number on result_queue:
                task_queue_size_lock.release()
                result_queue.put(number_1)
                with result_queue_size.get_lock():
                    result_queue_size.value += 1
                task_queue.task_done()
            else:
                number_2 = task_queue.get()
                task_queue_size.value -= 1
                task_queue_size_lock.release()
                # No lock is held for the actual reduction operation:
                result_queue.put(number_1 + number_2)
                with result_queue_size.get_lock():
                    result_queue_size.value += 1
                # Since we have tasken off 2 elements from the task queue:
                task_queue.task_done()
                task_queue.task_done()

def multiprocess_sum(array):
    n = len(array)
    if n == 1:
        return array[0]

    task_queue = multiprocessing.JoinableQueue()
    # You should be iterating array, not to_sun and
    # using a comprehension for its side effect is not Pythonic:
    for element in array:
        task_queue.put(element)
    task_queue_size = multiprocessing.Value('i', n)

    result_queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
    result_queue_size = multiprocessing.Value('i', 0)

    condition = multiprocessing.Condition()

    processes = [
        CustomProcess(name=str(i),
                      task_queue=task_queue,
                      result_queue=result_queue,
                      task_queue_size=task_queue_size,
                      result_queue_size=result_queue_size,
                      condition=condition,
                      )
        for i in range(8)
    ]
    for process in processes:
        process.start()

    while True:
        print('n =', n)

        # Wait for task_queue to be emptied:
        task_queue.join()

        # Now we can be sure that the child processes are no longer retrieving from the task queue
        # and putting items on the result queue:

        n = result_queue_size.value
        if n == 1:
            print('n =', n)
            result = result_queue.get()
            # Tell child processes to terminate:
            with condition:
                task_queue_size.value = -1
                condition.notify_all()
            return result

        # Child processes get their input from task queue.
        # So we must get items from the result queue and move them to the task queue.
        # The task queue size is now 0 so this should pause the child processes.
        for _ in range(n):
            task_queue.put(result_queue.get())
        result_queue_size.value = 0
        # Allow children to run
        with condition:
            # The new n value will be half of the previous n value (more or less)
            task_queue_size.value = n
            condition.notify_all()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    to_sum = [i for i in range(1350)]
    print(sum(to_sum))


    for i in range(5):
        print(multiprocess_sum(to_sum))
```

Prints:

```None
910575
task queue size: 1350
task queue size: 675
task queue size: 338
task queue size: 169
task queue size: 85
task queue size: 43
task queue size: 22
task queue size: 11
task queue size: 6
task queue size: 3
task queue size: 2
task queue size: 1
910575
task queue size: 1350
task queue size: 675
task queue size: 338
task queue size: 169
task queue size: 85
task queue size: 43
task queue size: 22
task queue size: 11
task queue size: 6
task queue size: 3
task queue size: 2
task queue size: 1
910575
task queue size: 1350
task queue size: 675
etc.
```

**Update 2**

But simpler yet is to use a multiprocessing pool and to pass to the worker function pairs of items to be reduced:

```py
import multiprocessing
from itertools import chain

def custom_process(pair):
    return pair[0] + pair[1] if len(pair) == 2 else pair[0]

def multiprocess_sum(array):
    n = len(array)
    if n == 1:
        return array[0]

    results = array
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(8)
    while True:
        print('n =', n)
        if n == 1:
            break

        # Create pairs:
        pairs = zip(results[:n//2], results[n//2:])
        # Did we start with an odd number of elements?
        if n % 2 == 1:
            pairs = chain(pairs, ((results[-1],),))
        # specify a chunksize for improved performance:
        results = list(pool.imap_unordered(custom_process, pairs))
        n = len(results)
    result = results[0]
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    return result

if __name__ == "__main__":
    to_sum = [i for i in range(1350)]
    print(sum(to_sum))


    for i in range(5):
        print(multiprocess_sum(to_sum))
```

Prints:

```None
910575
n = 1350
n = 675
n = 338
n = 169
n = 85
n = 43
n = 22
n = 11
n = 6
n = 3
n = 2
n = 1
910575
n = 1350
n = 675
```

Comment: Thanks you for the answer, this is a different, though nonetheless valid approach of handling the problem of a multiprocessed sum. Unfortunately, I am trying to parallelise a reduction operation and not simply sum a list using multiprocessing, so your answer though valid, does not help my case as I do not want to split the list in 8 smaller lists, but want to reduce the one list using multiple processes. You are correct in pointing out the serial nature of my implementation and I would be happy if you had any other ideas in how to avoid the race condition it attempts to prevent. Best regards

Comment: Python has a function [`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html?highlight=reduce#functools.reduce) that performs any arbitrary reduction. I have updated the answer to show how it is used. What type of operation if not addition do you need to perform where my approach would not work for you but yours does? If you have such a case, then, you should update your question with the specific case.

Comment: I have updated the code to do it more or less in the way you attempted. Please read the comments in the code. Again, this seems a bit convoluted,

Comment: I have updated the answer again to do it "your way" but I now create the child processes only once per run. I have also added a different way of thinking about doing the reduction as **Update 2**, which happens to use a multiprocessing pool.

Comment: Thank you for the updates, they truly do provide a much better way of implementing a multiprocessed reduce operation! As for your question on when your approach wouldn't work - it would. It just was fundamentally different to the process I was trying to implement - parallel reduction. In CUDA it makes much more sense as one has access to thousands of cores and can make a O(n) sum to O(log n) if the size is not too big. With just 8 CPU cores...not as much. The goal for me was the implementation of the algorithm, the ineffectiveness of it in Python was clear from the start.

Comment: I have updated the answer because I discovered there was a possibility of the child processes hanging.

Comment: Even doing it "your way", reducing  n=1350 numbers still requires 1349 reductions. Assuming no overhead incurred by using multiprocessing, then if you have N processors to apply to the problem, then you could at best reduce the running time by a factor of N, which still makes the running time O(n) for any given value N. So I can't see how your **Update** code (or the comparable **Update 2** code) runs  any faster than mine. In fact, I modified both my solution and yours to sleep for .1 seconds for each reduction operation to simulate a more costly reduction and mine took slightly less time.

Comment: Take a look at this article:
https://shreeraman-ak.medium.com/parallel-reduction-with-cuda-d0ae10c1ae2c

and the accepted answer for:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53372549/time-complexity-of-parallel-reduction-algorithm#:~:text=If%20we%20have%20P%20threads,%2FP)*log%20P).

Comment: @Tary This seems to confirm what I said, i.e. you need to be doing 1349 reductions if your input consists of 1350 numbers. *In theory* if you have N processors you can reduce the running time by a factor of N. The article talked about using the *many* processors of a GPU. Since we only have 8 processors here, it seems simpler to just assign to each process one eighth of the numbers and then do the final 7 reductions serially. Although technically (slightly) more reductions are being done than the minimum possible, there is so much less overhead per reduction.  (more...)

Comment: @Tary The cost of doing a reduction would have to be much larger so that saving the cost of 7 reductions more than compensates the increased overhead surrounding doing a reduction -- or to even make using multiprocessing in general perform better than a serial solution.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. As mentioned in a comment above by me, using only 8 processors makes the algorithm very inefficient. With efficiency in mind, your very first solution would be the go to. My goal though, is not efficiency. It was the implementation of a parallel reduction algorithm in Python. Your first solution, in my opinion, was fundamentally different to a parallel reduction and as such (even though it performs better in this case) was rejected. Your updates ,on the other hand, provide the requested solution: An implementation that does not hang when faced with higher inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Using a manager solves the problem.

```
import multiprocessing
"""
Using a manager avoids the problem where the program will hang if the input is too big.
"""

class CustomProcess(multiprocessing.Process):

    def __init__(self, name, task_queue, result_queue, lock, chunks=2, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(name=name, *args, **kwargs)
        self.name = name
        self.task_queue = task_queue
        self.result_queue = result_queue
        self.chunks = chunks
        self.lock = lock

    def run(self):
        while True:
            """
            Using a lock to avoid a race condition where 2 threads both get a number, then
            both to get another, but it is None so they both put the number back resulting in a result queue
            with bigger size. For example:
            Expected result_queue_size = 500, current_queue_size 499, after summation of 1 and 2 we will add 3 to result queue
            achieving 500.
            With race condition result is 501.
            [1, 2, None, None]
            Thread 1 gets 1.
            Thread 2 gets 2.
            Thread 1 gets None and puts 1 in result queue instead of getting 2 and summing.
            Thread 2 gets None and puts 2 in result queue instead of just getting the first None and returning.
            A lock on both gets removes the race condition.
            """
            with self.lock:
                if not self.task_queue.empty():
                    number_1 = self.task_queue.get()
                    self.task_queue.task_done()
                    if number_1 is None:
                        #Poison pill - terminate.
                        print(f"Terminated {self.name}")
                        return
                else:
                    #Queue empty - terminate.
                    return
                if not self.task_queue.empty():
                    number_2 = self.task_queue.get()
                    self.task_queue.task_done()
                    if number_2 is None:
                        #Cannot compute sum of 1 number so just add number_1 to result_queue and terminate since poison pill
                        #acquired.
                        self.result_queue.put(number_1)
                        print(f"Terminated {self.name}")
                        return
                else:
                    self.result_queue.put(number_1)
                    #Queue empty, put the 1 number in result queue and terminate.
                    return
            self.result_queue.put(number_1 + number_2)


def multiprocess_sum(array):
    if len(array) == 1:
        return array[0]
    lock = multiprocessing.Lock()

    with multiprocessing.Manager() as manager:

        task_queue = manager.Queue()
        [task_queue.put(element) for element in to_sum]
        task_queue_size = len(array)

        while task_queue_size > 1:
            result_queue = manager.Queue()

            processes = [CustomProcess(name=str(i), task_queue=task_queue, result_queue=result_queue, lock=lock)
                        for i in range(8)]
            [task_queue.put(None) for process in processes]
            [process.start() for process in processes]
            #[process.join() for process in processes]
            task_queue.join()
            task_queue = result_queue
            task_queue_size = task_queue_size // 2 + task_queue_size % 2
        return result_queue.get()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    to_sum = [i for i in range(2000)]

    print(sum(to_sum))
    for i in range(5):
        print(multiprocess_sum(to_sum))
```

I must agree with user Booboo that this specific implementation is not the best (might be the worst, actually) for a performant parallel sum function. If you are looking for a parallel sum function, read his answer. If you are interested in why your program hangs when faced with big Queues, using a Manager should solve your problem. Should you have an implementation of a parallel reduce function (better handling of the poison pill race condition), please do share with the intent of bettering the provided implementation for those looking for that specifically.
Best regards,
Tary